# Magento2 - How to override magento2-base adminhtml JS files?

Tags: magento2, tinymce

I want to override `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js` file.

I know how to override Magento core module files and I've tried that, but it's not working.

Is there any other way to override Magento2-base admin files?

Answer (score 0):

Add **tiny_mce_src.js** file at

> app/design/frontend/Theme_namespace/your_theme/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js

then run following command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

(Use -f for force deploy on 2.2.x or later)

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Please let me know still if you have any issue.

Comment: This answer is for frontend not for adminhtml, actually, I have already tried that, but it's not working